# what is difference between set based queries and row by row based queries in t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not that good at t-sql, recently i heard about set based queries and row by row based queries in t-sql. I just want to improve my knowledge in t-sql. I just want to know the difference and also which queries are set base and which are row by row, I am confusing. Please anybody explain if possible with examples will be very helpful.. thanks.

Comment: Read everything Jeff Moden has to say on the subject; here is an example - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: thanks Mark, this link is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I can guess that you are talking about [cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).

If you are using set-based queries like:

```
update t1 set f1 where f2 = "something"
```

you are working with sets of records.

If you are using cursors MS SQL Server prosesses the record by record:

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE f2 = "something"

OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @v

IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
    PRINT '         <<None>>'     

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- do somethifg with current record

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

If it is possible you should use set-based queries as it generally faster and MS SQL Server can build better execution plan.

But sometimes the application logic is so complex that it is difficult to develop solution using only set-based queries and you can use cursors in this case.